# SQL query - count all ocurrences of variable in several columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a hard time with a query, in which I need to count all possible ocurrences of a certain value and display it. Imagine I have a table like this

```
----------------------------
| field1 | field2 | field3 |
----------------------------
|   a    |   a    |    b   |
----------------------------
|   c    |   b    |    a   |
----------------------------
```

and so, I want my query to return something like this:

```
-----------------------
| value_found | count |
-----------------------
|   a         |   3   |
-----------------------
|   b         |   2   |
-----------------------
|   c         |   1   |
-----------------------
```

I tried one that *almost* gave me what I needed but it is too long and possible not ideal, so thank you so much.

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: It is an incredible terrible design actually, but it wasn't made by me! haha

Comment: Well that's all right then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select field, count(*)
from (select field1 as field from t union all
      select field2 as field from t union all
      select field3 as field from t
     ) t
group by field;
```

Comment: Jeez, thanks, that's exactly it! It is almost what I had, except that I was using regular union and I was writing the count inside each inner select...